# pattern for get all tags

Tags: regex

I have this sample code:

```
<ul><li><a href="http://www.example.com/aaa" class="tag">aaa</a></li><li><a href="http://www.example.com/bbb" class="tag">bbb</a></li><li><a href="http://www.example.com/ccc" class="tag">ccc</a></li></ul>
```

I need to get `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc` tags, and I wrote this pattern:

```
/<a .* class=\"tag\">(.*?)<\/a>/
```

But this return wrong results. You can see result [here](https://regex101.com/r/fmSZU9/1).

What's happen and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Add a question mark after the first asterisk asterisk: `/<a .*? class=\"tag\">(.*?)<\/a>/`. You can investigate further about this by searching [greedy and lazy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) regex on google

Comment: @Rodolfo Thanks, I use `?` in second part, but I forgot use in first part. Why you don't post as an answer?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made your second `.*` non-greedy, but not your first.  Because of this greedy matching, it was matching everything from the opening `<a` right through to the end of the third opening `<a`.  The simple fix is to make the first non-greedy too:

```
<a .*? class=\"tag\">(.*?)<\/a>
```

Here's the updated [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fmSZU9/2).

That said, depending on what you have available in your language of choice, and whether or not you're ever expecting a (even very slighty) different HTML string, an HTML parser might be a better choice.